# ODOO 8 requires module pyboleto i can't install on python2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7

Whats I'll do ?

```
odoo@odoo-Aspire-ES1-572:~$ pip2 install pyboleto
Collecting pyboleto
  Using cached pyboleto-0.3.1.tar.gz
Collecting distribute (from pyboleto)
  Using cached distribute-0.7.3.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/distribute.egg-info
    writing requirements to pip-egg-info/distribute.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/distribute.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/distribute.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/distribute.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-wdypyY/distribute/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        setuptools.setup(**setup_params)
      File "/home/odoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/home/odoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/home/odoo/.pyenv/versions/2.7.12/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 177, in run
        writer = ep.load(installer=installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2241, in load
        if require: self.require(env, installer)
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2254, in require
        working_set.resolve(self.dist.requires(self.extras),env,installer)))
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2471, in requires
        dm = self._dep_map
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2682, in _dep_map
        self.__dep_map = self._compute_dependencies()
      File "pkg_resources.py", line 2699, in _compute_dependencies
        from _markerlib import compile as compile_marker
    ImportError: No module named _markerlib

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-wdypyY/distribute/
odoo@odoo-Aspire-ES1-572:~$ pip2 install _markerlib
Invalid requirement: '_markerlib'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 82, in __init__
    req = Requirement(req)
  File "/home/odoo/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
    requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "'_markerl'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
sudo apt-get update        # Fetches the list of available updates
sudo apt-get upgrade       # Strictly upgrades the current packages
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # Installs updates (new ones)
sudo pip install pyboleto
```